# Best font to use with Ubuntu Intellij Idea

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA very poorly renders editor fonts on Ubuntu. I have found a lot of questions and blog posts about this problem, but nothing satisfies me. What is a developer font that renders very well in IDEA on Ubuntu?

Comment: It's really annoyoing problem. I have installed Intellij on Fedora and it look like sux. Windows fonts are SUPERB in comparrison with Linux

Comment: this article helped me - http://urshulyak.com/?p=478 - it's beautiful on Ubuntu 14.10 + Gnome  3.12 + Java 1.8.0_31

Comment: Article link is not longer working, on that weird-to-navigate website.

Answer (score 17):

I'm using `Liberation Mono` which looks very good with Ubuntu 12.04 and IDEA 11.
Others I've liked are `Envy Code R` and `DejaVu Sans Mono`.

Comment: Somehow, Dejavu Sans Mono looks best in IDEA 13 on ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Liberation Mono looks good.

Comment: There is a little difference but a prefer `Liberation Mono`

Answer (score 10):

[Check this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-57233). It has some recommendations for the fonts on Linux. **DejaVu Sans Mono** looks fine for me.

Comment: That font is really badly kerned by intelliJ

Answer (score 2):

Consolas with disabled hints - my decision. Much, much better!
Links to be checked:
1. http://linuxforum.ru/viewtopic.php?pid=262225#p262225 (consolas for Fedora)
2. http://gleamynode.net/articles/2280/
3. https://askubuntu.com/questions/32624/ugly-fonts-in-netbeans-how-can-i-make-it-use-the-system-font

Answer (score 0):

I use CMU Typewriter Text font. Anonymous Pro is also great.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend YaHei Consolas for IDEA. The font is very useful, and you can take a try.

Comment: Do you have any connection with `YaHei Consolas` ? If no, please state it... since your answer could be seen as biased.